# Arduino String checking SIM900A GSM module programming code

Tags: string, if-statement, module, arduino, gsm

I am working with SIM 900A module, where I need to turn on and off my relays through sms.

Basically I have used a GSM sms code to receive sms and stored the same into a string variable and then check whether there is "ON" or "On" or "on" in my string. This does not work and the program is running on the ELSE LOOP only, it is somehow escaping it in the IF loop.

Can anyone please help?

Code below:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM900A(9, 10);
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    SIM900A.begin(9600);
    pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
    Serial.println("Program Started");
    SIM900A.println("AT+CMGD=ALL");
    SIM900A.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0");
}

void loop(){
    if (SIM900A.available()>0){
        String k=SIM900A.readString();
        Serial.println("*** RECEIVED SMS ***");
        Serial.println(k);
        int len=k.length();
        Serial.println("the length is ");
        Serial.println(len);

        // Remove first 51 characters
        Serial.println("After removing first 51 characters");

        k.remove(0, 51);
        Serial.println(k);
        len = k.length();
        Serial.println("the length is ");
        Serial.println(len);
        // Remove \r\n from tail
        k.remove(len - 2, 2);Serial.println("After removing first r & n characters");
        Serial.println("the length is ");
        len = k.length();
        Serial.println(len);
        Serial.println(k);
        String L=k;
        Serial.println(L);

        if((L.equals("ON"))||(L.equals("On"))||(L.equals("on"))){
            Serial.println("now relay can be on");
            digitalWrite(13,HIGH);delay(5000);
        }
        else{
            digitalWrite(13,LOW);
            Serial.println("Else loop executed");
        };
        Serial.println("*** END SMS ***");
    };
}
```

Comment: can you post the serial output? hard to say without seeing what  Serial.println(L); does

Comment: When the program receives no sms ,, it first shows something on the serial monitor startup

Program Started
*** RECEIVED SMS ***
AT+CMGD=ALL
AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0

ERROR

the length is 
39
After removing first 51 characters

the length is 
0
After removing first r & n characters
the length is 
0


Else loop executed
*** END SMS ***

Comment: @A.ANoman Can you please choose a more descriptive text then "adjust coding of the format syntax semantics". You use this on basically every edit, and it doesn't really explain why you're making the changes. Avoid bolding text randomly, as it's not needed. Some changes you do are helpful (Changing links to images, some code formatting), but others I feel are destructive (Which is why you are frequently getting reject votes). Most posts you edit have more that can be fixed. You can remove noise, (Salutations like "Hi/Thanks") and use the rejections/edits as feedback of what should be changed).

Comment: @FrankerZ I will try to follow your advice.

Answer (score 0):

something to try:

```
void loop()
{
    if (SIM900A.available()>0){
        String k=SIM900A.readString();

        Serial.println("*** RECEIVED SMS ***");
        if(k.indexOf("On") > -1 || k.indexOf("On") > -1 || k.indexOf("on") > -1){
            Serial.println("now relay can be on");    
            digitalWrite(13,HIGH);delay(5000);
        }
        else{
            digitalWrite(13,LOW);Serial.println("Else loop executed");
        };

        Serial.println("*** END SMS ***");
};
```

Comment: Just tried the "indexof" command...WOW ..it works ..Thank you very much.

Comment: Tell me one thing ..What is wrong with my code ? ? ? why it didn't work as expected ?

Comment: I would need to see the output of the print command to be able to answer that for sure, but I've got a feeling it's because theres a space or another \r\n that you're not cleaning out of the response